# How to find exact confidence intervals for a quantile (assuming iid)?

Tags: confidence-interval, quantiles, order-statistics

Assume $X_1, ..., X_n$ are iid (distribution unknown). I want to find exact confidence intervals for the common quantile $q_\alpha$. Can this be done *exactly* given some confidence level $p$?

I know of a method that uses *order statistics* to do this, i.e. we try to find the $i$th and $j$th largest samples, $i < j$, and bound $q_\alpha$ with an interval using these order statistics, like $P(q_\alpha \in [X^j, X^i]) = 0.95$, where $X^j$ is the $j$th largest value in the sample, etc.

But this can't be done exactly for some fixed level $p$. Is there a method that does work exactly?

Comment: I believe the answer may be a conditional yes: you need to be willing to use randomized confidence limits.